# Windows's 7 C: permission

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, ntfs

I need to give to Users group read/write authorization to the C:\ folder (only this folder, not its subdirs).
I'm using this command as administrator:

```
icacls "c:/" /grant Users:M
```

This works for many PC, however I have just one where this doesn't work... I simply can not create a new file in c:\ and when I try i get a permission error. I checked all permissions and I'm sure there is not any "deny" rules. What can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access system root (C:) the user must be member of **Backup Operators** and the **UAC** must be disabled.